# How to access first and last timestamp in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to have a string of the first and the last timestamp (I'm using them as index) in my dataframe to use it later. I already searched for it on the internet, but couldn't find it.

This is how I read my .csv file

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        df = pandas.read_csv(csvfile, 
                parse_dates=True, 
                index_col=0, 
                sep=';', 
                skipinitialspace=True, 
                low_memory=False, 
                names=range(0,n))
```

I tried it using df.iloc[0], but couldn't get it right. How can I just get the timestamps (as strings)?

Example csv:

```
                       1    2
2015-07-02 21:40:00 -2.7 -2.7
2015-07-02 21:50:00 -2.5 -2.5
2015-07-02 22:00:00 -2.5 -2.5
```

I'm trying to get the first (2015-07-02 21:40:00) and the last (2015-07-02 22:00:00) timestamp.

Comment: Sorry but `df.iloc[0]` and `df.iloc[-1]` will return the first and last row, what string are you talking about here?

Comment: I'm using the timestamps as an index and I want to get those indices (as a string). I updated the post

Comment: So are you after just `df.index[0]` and `df.index[-1]`?

Comment: Do you want the first and last *index*, or do you want the earliest and latest *timestamp*?

Comment: Why use with here? ```with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:``` You don't need it with ```pandas.read_csv```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you, could you write an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Your question is horribly unclear to me please post what the first few rows of your df look like and what **exactly** you are trying to achieve into your question, not as a comment

Comment: I added an example .csv file. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What kind of string do you want?

```
df.index.min()
df.index.max()
```

gets you something like

```
In [8]: df.index.min()
Out[8]: Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Dont know if there is any flag for its output. Personally, I just do some - probably stupid - hardcoded stuff like

```
Maxi_date1 = str(df.index.max())
Maxi_date = Maxi_date1[0:10]
```

to get for example only `YYYY-MM-DD`.

**EDIT**

I just got into a situation myself again where I excessively need this functionality and since this Q/A has had a few views, here's an update to make it more complete:

Mostly I only need specific parts of the time, e.g. the year. While the above also works (simply a `[0:3]` to get the year), using the inbuilt functions for it is probably better.

To get only the year or month:

```
Maxi_date = df.index.min()
Maxi_year = Maxi_date.year
Maxi_mon = Maxi_date.month
```

and so on, as listed [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#properties).

Comment: Nice update with the update! I suggest deleting the original part where you just use the substring. This will provide a more complete Q/A post for viewers.